# How can I dynamically add a total to the end of the row in Excel with Python?

Tags: javascript, python, excel-formula, python-3.6

```
for item in results:    
    titleformat = book.add_format({'bold': True, 'align': 'center'})
    center      = book.add_format({'align' : 'center'})

    usersheet.write(0, 0, "#"             , titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 1, "User"          , titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 2, "Group"         , titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 3, "SVN Commits"   , titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 4, "GIT Commits"   , titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 5, "GITLAB Commits", titleformat)
    usersheet.write(0, 6, "Gerrit Review" , titleformat)
.
.
.
.
    #### set column widths
    usersheet.set_column(userrowno, 0, 5)
    for i in range(1,26):
        usersheet.set_column(userrowno, i, 20)

    
    userrowno = userrowno + 1
```

With this piece of code, we dynamically create two Excel sheets. However, because the data is always changing, the last row looks different for each data. How can I dynamically write the total data at the end of each column in Python?[The TOTAL text in the picture should be generated as generic in the code and should be written at the end of each column.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZqf5.png)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to read this into a dataframe in pandas, sum on columns, then rewrite your sheet with the titles.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(path_to_sheet)
df.loc["Total"] = df.sum()
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_where_you_want)

...do what you're doing above with pandas writer object...

df.to_excel(writer)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Edit: you may need to set your index if you have non-numeric columns